# Spotify API queuing tracks?

Tags: android, spotify

For my application, I want to queue a list of tracks; I have already extracted the track ids using spotipy, and made an array of these track ids. However, I can't figure out how to queue the tracks to play one after the other.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
@Override               
public void onLoggedIn() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "User logged in");
    String[] song_artists = new String[] {"Gary Clark Jr.", "Thirty Seconds To Mars", "Theory of a Deadman", "Foo Fighters", "Ron Gallo", "cleopatrick", "grandson", "The Killers", "Royal Blood", "K.Flay", "Alice Merton", "Dashboard Confessional", "Tash Sultana", "DREAMERS", "Death From Above 1979", "8 Graves", "Queens of the Stone Age", "A Perfect Circle", "Cold War Kids", "The Wombats", "Beck", "Welshly Arms", "Highly Suspect", "Portugal. The Man", "The Glorious Sons", "AJR", "Barns Courtney", "Nothing But Thieves", "Linkin Park", "Marilyn Manson", "Papa Roach", "Fall Out Boy", "Kaleo", "Nothing More", "Prophets Of Rage", "Fozzy", "10 Years", "WALK THE MOON", "Foster The People", "Bishop Briggs", "Anti-Flag", "The Struts", "Greta Van Fleet", "U2", "J. Roddy Walston & The Business", "Weezer", "Vance Joy", "Green Day", "Stone Temple Pilots", "AWOLNATION"};
    String[] song_names = new String[] {"Come Together", "Walk On Water", "Rx (Medicate)", "The Sky Is A Neighborhood", "Young Lady, You're Scaring Me", "hometown", "Blood / / Water", "Run For Cover", "I Only Lie When I Love You", "Giver", "No Roots", "We Fight", "Jungle (Radio Edit)", "Painkiller", "Freeze Me", "Hang", "The Way You Used To Do", "The Doomed", "So Tied Up - moreBishop", "Turn", "Up All Night", "Legendary", "Little One", "Live In The Moment", "Everything Is Alright", "Sober Up", "Golden Dandelions", "Sorry", "Crawling - One More Light Live", "KILL4ME", "Born For Greatness", "HOLD ME TIGHT OR DON’T", "No Good", "Go To War", "Living On The 110", "Judas", "Novacaine", "Headphones", "Sit Next to Me", "Dream", "American Attraction", "One Night Only", "Safari Song", "American Soul", "The Wanting", "Happy Hour", "Lay It On Me", "Back in the USA", "Meadow", "Passion"};
    String[] song_ids = new String[] {"spotify:track:45HAjqRWiNv6mMPw4NvZrU", "spotify:track:5UMD1Iz7yyVK8Q5FLsVt3q", "spotify:track:7pV6zXFpCwrrmcosBAtp0o", "spotify:track:5vFshmrfuOng89bVtW33J9", "spotify:track:6PtIXICwmoxCgLjw2zApDs", "spotify:track:2kFKIFc5RSTlhuGed6ZNZ7", "spotify:track:1rFAG22RkvaM6BlpWQoZ47", "spotify:track:03YoRDLmG333y0ORu2D5A4", "spotify:track:1LbwMX3159t6QxG3u7DRWe", "spotify:track:5f8z7Cp7CY9T54Cnq1YVlh", "spotify:track:1LzguIGcb1qtA1Kw9pfwAP", "spotify:track:4vSGt6RC1GcfA07OGE3rcs", "spotify:track:5GI8QlM6RlyZjegB9CFk7U", "spotify:track:15BsrefgYpMgu1ZCIr8EJw", "spotify:track:3PBXTtPiOqfYcbc30ydVTz", "spotify:track:0hOgIGyEvAzfnk7mXfXEeM", "spotify:track:7dBMQbBKG6n9HkVXkUKnhQ", "spotify:track:54RaEDwHbCJKMdDq68EyKE", "spotify:track:53fUkhzh2EodCV8cfcxLQ8", "spotify:track:4GxWee692irccH1QOmRRLl", "spotify:track:6Z884oSfliz0mKqTJTXrwb", "spotify:track:3tA2Khh4RpQThUoX22PQAG", "spotify:track:5y1jgbDNgTfxoWXv3FhH2Q", "spotify:track:60eOMEt3WNVX1m1jmApmnX", "spotify:track:42lrhaZzqJqCYHlfQTGozP", "spotify:track:2QCndYqRherBtKjBpyySC6", "spotify:track:39mypRmMWQJpVdCsWNxT3h", "spotify:track:7cJgiPDOlpnYjlBPcrT9kW", "spotify:track:5xK7K6C2Gpme46F9paZH1t", "spotify:track:5EsJkqTznyjUWzB3g9lk47", "spotify:track:5cRPdqpWkaNmIbPi6wJDg2", "spotify:track:5VJ1eVOnlAlaA2mQcwmKC8", "spotify:track:0Tr5G2mE56eLUGvCaXRM8I", "spotify:track:1mU8A0bKStnhYuS043o6Je", "spotify:track:3mBjUka3HBmY2TRL7HqyEE", "spotify:track:2QQDH8gt4nyxFu2XX6bhG8", "spotify:track:0uyDAijTR0tOuH24hxDhE5", "spotify:track:3v94lXvmQ4q80RJpYnBuGY", "spotify:track:4BdGO1CaObRD4La9l5Zanz", "spotify:track:23fR48mfaGSXCn5MM687U6", "spotify:track:3N6wNh5vk9Hshfvr9YIiUL", "spotify:track:3DRZp9kykKCfnaU1Kd2AWY", "spotify:track:3H5EsEaJZNdmtuyWOWdSC9", "spotify:track:7F0wm6AJKih5JU0fjEbzkr", "spotify:track:06h7n5DewHqOu8bwsTfhoL", "spotify:track:20d716Zgi9dRE2g7wnhMqt", "spotify:track:7MUNNBJKYo3cdokp06wEOB", "spotify:track:53oEpGga4UriwcOKc35LpM", "spotify:track:7tIO5ACb24HS9rqhAXK3OG", "spotify:track:2E2r97GUoaRP3jCVX3nLa5"};
    mPlayer.playUri(null, song_ids[0], 0, 0);
    mPlayer.playUri(null, song_ids[1], 0, 0);
}
```

The mPlayer.playUri lines only play the second song.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mPlayer.playUri(null, song_ids[0], 0, 0);
mPlayer.queue(null, song_ids[1]);
```

Comment: It's still not working -- it's only playing the first song, but does not play what was queued.

Comment: Pass a Player.OperationCallback into the queue call instead of `null` and see if an error is returned.